# Untouched files being added to Untracked section in git

Tags: git

I am using git as my version controller. When I moved from a branch A(older) to branch B(newer) there were a lot files been added to the Untracked section most of them where .gitignore files. Is there any way to move to fresh Branch B without any of these changes.

Comment: Have there been any changes to `.gitignore` between the heads of these branches? When on branch B, check it using `git diff branchA .gitignore`.

Comment: No when I did a git diff the result was empty